# using reference (&) in foreach add `&` in output array? is it a bug

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, pass-by-reference, array-splice

I am using PHP 5.3.5, and I am stuck with an error. I have an array

```
  $input = array( 
                0=>array(
                        'a'=>'one0',
                        'b'=>'two0',
                        'c'=>'three0',
                        'd'=>'four0',
                        'e'=>'five0'
                        ),
                1=>array(
                        'a'=>'one1',
                        'b'=>'two1',
                        'c'=>'three1',
                        'd'=>'four1',
                        'e'=>'five1'
                        )
            );
```

I use [`array_splice`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to remove the initial two values from each array 
 by using `&`(value by reference) in foreach

```
foreach ($input as $bk => &$bv) {
         $op[]=array_splice($bv,0,2);        
}
```

Now when I see the `$input` then it adds a `&` just before the second array.

`var_dump($input);` shows this

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'c' => string 'three0' (length=6)
      'd' => string 'four0' (length=5)
      'e' => string 'five0' (length=5)
  1 => & <====================================From where this `&` comes?
    array
      'c' => string 'three1' (length=6)
      'd' => string 'four1' (length=5)
      'e' => string 'five1' (length=5)
```

Where does `&` come from and how does it produce such array? Is it valid?

If I remove `&` in the foreach, it does not gives me desired array. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty counter-intuitive but it isn't actually a bug. When you use references in a loop, you're advised to unset the reference right after the loop:

```
foreach ($input as $bk => &$bv) {
    $op[]=array_splice($bv,0,2);        
}
unset($bv);
```

Comment: Oh Thanks. i was banging my head since 3 hours . Thanks

Comment: I think its better to use `array_slice()`

Comment: @diEcho: they do different things. `array_splice` removes elements from the array. `array_slice` doesn't